# How to quickly fill a numpy array with values from separate calls to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to fill a numpy array with generated values. These values are generated by a generator function. The array length is not too long, <100 usually, but this array is generated many times, so I wanted to know if it can be optimized with some fancy usage of numpy.

So far I can already do it with vanilla python:

```
def generate():
   return generated_data

array = np.asarray([generate() for _ in range(array_length)])
```

I've also tried to use `np.full(shape, fill_value)`:

```
np.full((array_length, generated_data_size), generate())
```

But this is calls the `generate()` function only once, not once for every index in the array.

I've also tried `np.vectorize()`, but I couldn't make it generate a appropriately shaped array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing NumPy can do to accelerate the process of repeatedly calling a function not designed to interact with NumPy.

The "fancy usage of numpy" way to optimize this is to manually rewrite your `generate` function to use NumPy operations to generate entire arrays of output instead of only supporting single values. That's how NumPy works, and how NumPy *has* to work; any solution that involves calling a Python function over and over again for every array cell is going to be limited by Python overhead. NumPy can only accelerate work that actually happens in NumPy.

If NumPy's provided operations are too limited to rewrite `generate` in terms of them, there are options like rewriting `generate` with Cython, or using `@numba.jit` on it. These mostly help with computations that involve complex dependencies from one loop iteration to the next; they don't help with external dependencies you can't rewrite.

If you cannot rewrite `generate`, all you can do is try to optimize the process of getting the return values into your array. Depending on array size, you may be able to save some time by reusing a single array object:

```
In [32]: %timeit x = numpy.array([random.random() for _ in range(10)])
The slowest run took 5.13 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an
 intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 5.44 µs per loop
In [33]: %%timeit x = numpy.empty(10)
   ....: for i in range(10):
   ....:     x[i] = random.random()
   ....: 
The slowest run took 4.26 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an
 intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 2.88 µs per loop
```

but the benefit vanishes for larger arrays:

```
In [34]: %timeit x = numpy.array([random.random() for _ in range(100)])
10000 loops, best of 5: 21.9 µs per loop
In [35]: %%timeit x = numpy.empty(100)
   ....: for i in range(100):
   ....:     x[i] = random.random()
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 5: 22.8 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

## Conventional "Pythoninc"

[List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions), or the [map function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) could both be possible solutions for you:

```
from random import random
import numpy as np

np.array(list(map(lambda idx: random(), range(10))))
np.array([random() for idx in range(10)])
```

## "Need-for-speed"

Maybe pre-alocating the memory will shave off a micro second or two(?)

```
array = np.empty(10)
for idx in range(10):
    array[idx] = random()
```

See [Nathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644927/4039619) for an even better solution.

## Function Vectorisation

A function can be "vectorised" using numpy:

```
def rnd(x):
    return random()

fun = np.vectorize(rnd)
array = fun(range(10))
```

Comment: It should be ```np.array(list(map(lambda idx: random(), range(10))))``` or it doesn't work. And you did understand it correctly, ill go and test it now to see if it's any faster.

Comment: It's actually more about the cleanliness of the code. I was hoping there would be some elegant numpy function to do this. It's actually fast enough as is, but I'm just trying to learn some numpy tricks, that benefit both code readability and performance. (and using the list(map()) is actually slower)

Comment: That last one is what I was trying with np.vectorize(). But it's extremely slow compared to the other ones. 1000000 array creations using ```[random() for _ in range(10)]``` is ~3.8 seconds, using ```list(map(lambda))``` is ~4.6 seconds, and using ```np.vectorize()``` is ~58.5 seconds

Comment: `numpy.vectorize` is provided for convenience, not for speed; the returned function object executes far slower than code written in terms of "natively" vectorized NumPy operations.

Comment: It's going to be exceptionally slow the way you're using it, creating an entire dummy array (in a particularly inefficient manner, by implicit conversion from a `range` object) just to use it for ignored argument values, and introducing an extra layer of indirection just to ignore the dummy values. This is absolutely not a "Pythonic" way to write the code, and not a case where it makes sense to use `numpy.vectorize`.

Comment: As for "memory allocation + a loop" being fast, it's not. In fact, it's actually slower than the list comprehension version for larger arrays. However, if you reuse the array instead of creating a new one each time, that saves enough time to win for smaller arrays. (The "memory allocation + a loop" version is also doing far more incidental allocation than it might seem.)

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to make a `ufunc` from your `generate` function:

```py
gen_array = np.frompyfunc(generate, 0, 1) # takes 0 args, returns 1
array = gen_array(np.empty(array_length))
```

This is a bit faster for me than the "need for speed" version from [Sigve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55630811/9200529).

Comment: Thanks, I like the solution, my generated values are sequences though, so it sadly doesn't work in my case.