# How to plug f(k) in to a series?

Tags: python

Lets suppose you have f(x)=x^2 and you want a series from k=1 to n of f(k). How would you enter it in python and print the result?
I tried doing this for n=10

```
n=10

def f(x):

  return x^2
  sum = 0

  for k in range(1, n):

    Sum = sum + f(k)
```

I don't know how to print it let alone whether I did it correctly.

I know you can represent a sum of k^2 as n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 but I am just using x^2 as an example.

Comment: I came here for the title.

Answer (score 0):

First off `sum` is a builtin function so you should not use it as a variable name as python will simply let you overwrite the variable in the spirit of "we are all consenting adults here". Example

```
type(sum)
# <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
sum = 0
type(sum)
# <type 'int'>
```

Now to your question. One way is to first generate the sequence and use the aforementioned `sum` function as the following examples show.

1. Generate the sequence using a so-called *list comprehension* to evaluate the function for each element in a range:

   ```
   n = 5
   def f(x):
       return x*x

   print([ f(i) for i in range(n)])
   # [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
   print(sum([ f(i) for i in range(n)]))
   # 30
   ```
2. Use the builtin `map` function to apply a function, either defined using `def` or `lambda`, on a range:

   ```
   n = 10
   f = lambda x: x*x
   print(map(f, range(n)))
   # [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
   # one line equivalent : print(map(lambda x: x*x, range(n)))
   print(sum(map(f, range(n))))
   # 30
   ```

Alternatively, you can follow your train of thought and use a simple loop and a variable:

```
n = 5
f = lambda x: x*x
s = 0

for i in range(n):
    s += f(i)

print(s)
# 30
```

Finally, if speed/efficiency is a factor that you have to account for you can have a look at the `numpy`  library. See for instance one of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55630811/4039619) on applying a funcion over a range.